# Edit sqlite file outside the app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

For testing, I wanted to manipulate the sqlite database for my Android app. I copied the database file to my laptop, edited the file with the [Sqlite manager plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), and copied the file back to its directory.

I thought that would work, but the app crashes, because it can't open the database. The ownership and permissions of the file is like before.

Can someone explain to me why it won't work, or suggest how I could do instead?

Comment: can you post a logcat of the crash?

Comment: To provide a prepopulated database, you have to put it in the `assets` folder and make sure to delete the previous version of the database from the `/data/data/...` path. Then copy it programmatically to that working path.

Comment: @iagreen, the logcat doesn't really tell much, just that it couldn't open the database: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use Sqlite browser..[download here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) 
2.Pull your database to your computer.. 
3.Edit the database using sqlite browser 
4.Delete the  database from eclipse then push the edited database to your aplication Run the app to see the result